# SQL Get results back from every items in IN()

Tags: sql-server

Hi can some one help me with this?

I have made this query:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT(CAMPAIGN),
     count(STATUS)
FROM    
C18_101 INNER JOIN CLIENT_10 ON C18_101.ID = CLIENT_10.ID
WHERE CAMPAIGN in ('Batch 1','Batch 2','Batch 3','Batch 4','Batch 5') AND STATUS = 'Pending' 
GROUP BY  CAMPAIGN,STATUS
```

The result looks like this:

```
Batch 2     241

Batch 3     321

Batch 4     575

Batch 5     429
```

I also need a result for Batch1 even when there is none.

Comment: Query seems to be ok. Check if you actually have data for 'Batch 1' where its status is pending

Comment: @ARS: He wants `Batch 1` even if there is no record.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Oh I missed that point.. I guess the painkiller i took for my back pain is affecting my concentration :)

Comment: Hi, I know there is no data for batch 1 I need a 0 back when there is no data.

Comment: This is quite messed up SQL. You have a COUNT *and* GROUP BY on STATUS. DISTINCT is per-row, *not* per column. No idea which column comes from which table.

Comment: And is CAMPAIGN unique in C18_10?

Comment: Vote to close as OP won't clarify question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
     X.CAMPAIGN,
     count(STATUS)
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT CAMPAIGN FROM C18_101) X
    LEFT JOIN
    CLIENT_10 C ON X.ID = C.ID AND C.STATUS = 'Pending' 
GROUP BY
    X.CAMPAIGN
```

1. You either GROUP BY or aggregate, not both
2. You distinct before the JOIN to ensure your counts are correct per CAMPAIGN
3. Do you really need a campaign filter? If so, add to the derived table X

Comment: Thank you I am very pleased with the help, however the campaign is in the table CLIENT_10 now I get some messages on the join

Comment: @user2358570: like what please?

Comment: SELECT

 CLIENT_NLE001.SIZO_CAMPAIGN_ID__C,

count(X.lib_status)


FROM
    

(SELECT DISTINCT CLIENT_NLE001.SIZO_CAMPAIGN_ID__C FROM C18_NLE001) X
    

INNER JOIN CLIENT_NLE001 ON X.INDICE = CLIENT_NLE001.INDICE
    
AND C.STATUS = 'Missed Calls Rules' 


GROUP BY
    X.SIZO_CAMPAIGN_ID__C

the response is:



[FreeTDS][SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "CLIENT_NLE001.SIZO_CAMPAIGN_ID__C" could not be bound.
[FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'INDICE'.
[FreeTDS][SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "C.STATUS" could not be bound.
[FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'lib_status'.

Comment: @user2358570: Try and apply what I wrote to your SQL. Why use X.Status? Why change table names? Why not answer the comments. Don't waste our time please

Comment: I'm sorry, you've really helped me, with your help it was possible to make this:


SELECT
Q2.result,
Q2.text
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(CLIENT_NLE001.SIZO_CAMPAIGN_ID__C) as result,  CLIENT_NLE001.SIZO_CAMPAIGN_ID__C as text FROM C18_NLE001 INNER JOIN CLIENT_NLE001 ON C18_NLE001.INDICE = CLIENT_NLE001.INDICE WHERE LIB_STATUS = 'Missed Calls Rules' GROUP BY ALL
    SIZO_CAMPAIGN_ID__C ) Q2

Comment: i do not change the names any more when I post something.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  CAMPAIGN,
     count(STATUS)
FROM    C18_101 
LEFT JOIN CLIENT_10 ON C18_101.ID = CLIENT_10.ID AND STATUS = 'Pending' 
WHERE CAMPAIGN in ('Batch 1','Batch 2','Batch 3','Batch 4','Batch 5') 
GROUP BY  CAMPAIGN
```

Comment: This is still wrong. DISTINCT is pre row, not per column. And you can't COUNT and GROUP BY